# How do I find all real numbers of Y with a nontrivial solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

My problem is: Find all real values of Y, if any, for which the system has a nontrivial solution.

$$2X_1 + 3X_2 = YX_1$$

$$4X_1 + 3X_2 = YX_2$$

Thank you.

Comment: Is X1 supposed to be $X_1$ etc, or is X supposed to be multiply?  We are guessing the first.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Subtract the right sides from the left sides, making the first $(2-Y)X_1+3X_2=0$  To have a non-trivial solution the two equations must be multiples of each other.

Answer (score 1):

First, write the system as

> $$ (2-Y)X_1 + 3X_2 = 0 $$
>   $$ 4X_1 + (3-Y)X_2 = 0 .$$

The above is a homogeneous system and in order to get a non trivial solution then the determinant of the matrix of the coefficients of $X_1$ and $X_2$ has to be zero.